# Java for loop iteration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, if-statement, for-loop, collections

In my application, I have list of values of type String, I am iterating throught it and comparing the values of each to another string and if it is true returning true value else false.

```
List<String> roleNames = new ArrayList<String>();
roleNames.add("AAA");
roleNames.add("MMM");
for (int i=0 ; i<roleNames.size();i++){
//  if(loggedInRole.equals(roleNames.get(i))){
    if("AAA".equals(roleNames.get(i))){
        enableLink = "true";
    }
    else {
        enableLink = "false";
    }
}
```

In my above code i am expecting the result as true but in the second itertion it returning the result as false. How to reolve this issue?

Comment: Well in the second iteration the value is "MMM", not "AAA"... is that really your complete loop? Note that you're not actually *returning* anything...

Comment: why did u not declare enableLink as a boolean?

Comment: hint: instead of looping through the `ArrayList` you can just have `enableLink = roleNames.contains("AAA");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `break` statement when you find a match. If you don't break out of the loop then the next iteration will set `enableLink` back to `"false"` when it iterates over `"MMM"`.

Also you should set `enableLink` to `"false"` before you start the loop. The standard "search an array" loop looks like:

```
enableLink = "false";

for (int i = 0; i < roleNames.size(); i++) {
    if ("AAA".equals(roleNames.get(i))) {
        enableLink = "true";
        break;
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, you don't need an explicit loop. You could write:

```
boolean enableLink = roleNames.contains("AAA");
```

Comment: Its as simple as that, thank you so much for reminding me of BREAK, It worked.Thank you a TONE

Answer (score 5):

You have to break the loop when you found one value that satisfied your condition, otherwise `enableLink` will be `"true"` only if the last element of your list is equals to `"AAA"` in your case.

You should also look at the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method.